# Laravel: Load a page and then send a mail

Tags: php, email, laravel

i am trying to load page first and then activate the $mailer to send email. because when i click on to go to next page its taking time, because its sending emails and then it is loading so,

what is the best way to do it. or any way. because i cant figure it out.

here is snippet

```
public function sInterest($project_id, AppMailer $mailer)
{

    $project = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
    if($project->investment){
        $mailer->sendInterestNotificationI($user, $project);
        $mailer->sendInterestNotificationD($project, $user);
        $mailer->sendInterestNotificationA($project, $user);
        return view('projects.offer', compact('project'));
    } 
}
```

is there a way $mailer to activate after returning a page?

Comment: Best way is to send the mail to a queue and process the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppMailer sendInterestNotification*() methods, replace sync email delivery with queued email delivery (see [Queueing Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#queueing-mail) in Laravel documentation)

Then page will be returned instantly, emails will be put in the corresponding queue. You will have to edit .env file to change the QUEUE driver and to start a queue listener as a separate process, [detailed documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#running-the-queue-listener) is given on Laravel website

There is no way you can return a page to browser and then run some extra commands in your controller.